# How to add MongoDB data source in Orbeon

Tags: mongodb, orbeon

How do I add a MongoDB data source to Orbeon CE? I have been browsing through all the xml config files without any luck and the Orbeon documentation doesn't help very much. Any help would be appreciated.

It is supposed to be achievable through the persistence api.

Edit:
And when having added the data source \ service under, for example, /fr/service/mongodb/* how do you make procedure calls to it from a form application, i.e. how do you use the /crud and /search to add and retreive information from the database?

Answer (score 3):

First note that support for MongoDB is at this point very much experimental. It is implemented as a servlet in [`MongoDBPersistence.scala`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fr/mongdb/MongoDBPersistence.scala), so you'll want to:

1. Edit Orbeon's `web.xml` declare that servlet in a `<servlet>`, and map `/fr/service/mongo/*`  to that servlet with a `<servlet-mapping>`.
2. Add a property telling Form Runner to use the MongoDB persistence layer: e.g. `<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"                          value="mongo"/>`.
3. Add a property telling Form Runner what the URI of the MongoDB persistence layer is, e.g. `<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.mongo.uri" value="/fr/service/mongo"/>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the values as you instructed with help from the documentation. Then I restarted tomcat. When I then tried to access it in the browser address field, it doesn't seem to find the MongoDBPersistence file, since it throws a ClassNotFoundException. The path I use is "org.orbeon.oxf.fr.mongodb.MongoDBPersistence" as suggested in the github home.

Comment: The package is `org.orbeon.oxf.fr.mongdb`, without a "o" in the name; see: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.0.0.beta2-ce/src/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fr/mongdb/MongoDBPersistence.scala. Not sure of this is a typo or was done on purpose ;).

Comment: Haha, your'e right. I looked at it many times and never saw it. Thanks. Now it worked.

Comment: `mongdb` is an accident: it should clearly be `mongodb`! We'll fix that.

Comment: Apparently not; I am looking at the 3.9 CE tag on GitHub https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commits/tag-release-3.9.0-ce and the MongoDB code wasn't there yet at the time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also discovered that later and changed my version to 4.0.

Comment: The package is now renamed and we [added a default configuration](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/877818c3698349b5bdfc7ebcd69160cfa7750647).

Comment: Please tell me if you are working on this or not because we need a working solution soon. Do you think that this issue will be addressed in a foreseeable future?

Comment: @johansson.lc We are not working on the MongoDB persistence layer but what issue are you referring to? There are no MongoDB open issues at this point. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/search?q=mongodb

Comment: Ok, an issue has now been created.

Comment: @johansson.lc Ah yes, the jar files… I forgot about that. Have you tried putting in the new jar files? Does it work for you when you do that? If you can point me to the new jars, and you confirmed that it works for you with those, I can just do the commit. (Also feel free to submit a pull request on GitHub.)